# Running a bash script after the kafka-connect docker is up and running

Tags: bash, docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following docker file

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.3.1

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/share/java

# JDBC-MariaDB
RUN wget -nv -P /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/ https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/java/connector-java-2.4.4/mariadb-java-client-2.4.4.jar

# SNMP Source
RUN wget -nv -P /tmp/ https://github.com/KarthikDuggirala/kafka-connect-snmp/releases/download/0.0.1.11/kafka-connect-snmp-0.0.1.11.tar.gz
RUN mkdir /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp && tar -xf /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp-0.0.1.11.tar.gz -C /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp/
RUN mv /tmp/kafka-connect-snmp/usr/share/kafka-connect/kafka-connect-snmp /usr/share/java/

# COPY script and make it executable
COPY plugins-config.sh /usr/share/kafka-connect-script/plugins-config.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/share/kafka-connect-script/plugins-config.sh"]

#entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT [ "./usr/share/kafka-connect-script/plugins-config.sh" ]
```

and the following bash script

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#script to configure kafka connect with plugins
#export CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
#export CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
url=http://$CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME:$CONNECT_REST_PORT/connectors
curl_command="curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} $url"
sleep_second=5
sleep_second_counter=0
max_seconds_to_wait=30

echo "Waiting for Kafka Connect to start listening on localhost"
echo "HOST: $CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME , PORT: $CONNECT_REST_PORT"
while [[ $(eval $curl_command) -eq 000 ]]
 do 
    echo "In"
    echo -e $date " Kafka Connect listener HTTP state: " $(eval $curl_command) " (waiting for 200) $sleep_second_counter"
    echo "Going to sleep for $sleep_second seconds"
    # sleep $sleep_second
    echo "Finished sleeping"
    # ((sleep_second_counter+=$sleep_second))
    echo "Finished counter"
done
echo "Out"
nc -vz $CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME $CONNECT_REST_PORT
```

I try to run the docker and using docker logs  to see whats happening, and I am expecting that the script would run and wait till the kafka connect is started. But apparently after say few seconds the script or (I dont know what is hanging) hangs and I do not see any console prints anymore.

I am a bit lost what is wrong, so I need some guidance on what is that I am missing or is this not the correct way

**What I am trying to do**

I want to have logic defined that I could wait for kafka connect to start then run the curl command

*curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"","config":{"connector.class":"com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.snmp.SnmpTrapSourceConnector","topic":"fm_snmp"}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors*

PS: I cannot use docker-compose way to do it, since there are places I have to use *docker run*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `ENTRYPOINT` will run when the container starts and will prevent the default `CMD` to run since the script will loop waiting for the server to be up , that is the script will loop forever since the CMD will not run.

you need to do one of the following:

start the kafka connect server in your Entrypoint and your script in CMD or running your script outside the container ....